# Writing half of an int array into a new text file

Tags: c, arrays, file, file-io, concurrency

In my program, I am trying to opens the text file provided at the command-line, and then creates two new text files values1.txt and values2.txt. The file from the command line contains 100 unique integer numbers. Half of the numbers are copied into values1.txt, the other half is copied into values2.txt.

However, when I tried to do it for values1.txt, I got the following values:

```
101
32758
0
0
176197744
32764
3
0
176197728
32764
0
0
-78325960
32758
0
0
1
0
-78326000
32758
0
0
1700966438
0
-78325096
32758
176197896
32764
176197952
32764
-78326000
32758
0
0
-80547345
32758
0
0
176197952
32764
0
0
0
0
0
0
-78326000
32758
-82942073
32758
8
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cfileexists(const char * filename){
    /* try to open file to read */
    FILE *file;
    if (file = fopen(filename, "r")){
        fclose(file);
            return 1;
    }   
} 

int main(int argc,char*argv[]){
    char *p= argv[1];
    int numArray[100];
    int i=0;
    int sum1arr[50];
    int sum2arr[50];

    if (! cfileexists(p)){
        printf("Error, unable to locate the data file %s\n", p);
        return 100;
    }
    for(i;i<100;i++){
        FILE *stream=fopen(p,"r");
        while(!feof(stream)){

        fscanf(stream,"%d",&numArray[i]);

        }
        FILE * fPtr = NULL;
        fPtr = fopen("values1.txt", "w");
        for(int j=0;j<50;j++){
            fprintf(fPtr,"%d\n",numArray[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

For comparison; this is the source txtfile:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
101
```

Comment: Every line have errors... Firstly, you don't create  values2.txt, you open values1.txt inside tow loops but never close it, the while loop not increment i, so numbers of  values1.txt are always copied into first case of numArray. This is why in value1.txt, the first line is correct

Comment: @MOehm How would I go about do so?

Comment: @Sirac I am supposed to create two new txtfiles: values1.txt and values2.txt. I have not created values2.txt because I wanted to make sure that values1.txt was good before moving on to values2.txt. Also, I added fclose(fPtr); but it does not change anything. The while loop that I wrote is for the first int array, where I get all of the integers from the source txtfile until the end of the file. Then I try to split the array into half, so that each half of the array can be put into two new txtfiles: values1.txt and values2.txt.

Comment: @anastaciu I don't think it is a problem, for me at least, it works when I test it.

Comment: @newuserr, it doesn't appeat to be a problem, but my optimized `-O3` compilation issues a warning in gcc and I don't like warnings, so I used the parenthesis, better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` statement has too many cycles, you should use the read cycle to also write, you also can use fscanf return to verify whe the file reaches it's end. If you don't need to save the values you can even use on singe `int` to temporarily store the value till it's written.

Here is a possibe implementation with comments:

[Live demo](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/ImpeccableAcademicKilobyte)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cfileexists(const char *filename) 
{
    /* try to open file to read */ 
    FILE *file;
    if ((file = fopen(filename, "r")))
    {
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }   
    return 0; //return 0 if file not found
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    if(argc != 2){      //check number of arguments
        puts("Wrong number of arguments");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);  //EXIT_FAILURE macro is more portable
    }

    FILE *stream;    
    FILE *fPtr = NULL;
    FILE *fPtr2 = NULL;

    int numArray[100];
    int i = 0;

    fPtr = fopen("values1.txt", "w");
    fPtr2 = fopen("values2.txt", "w");

    //you can use fopen to check file nstead of the 
    //function, it returns null if no file is opened
    if (!(stream = fopen(argv[1], "r")))
    {
        perror("Error, unable to locate the data file"); //also prints error signature
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    //check input, stop when there is nothing else to read
    while (fscanf(stream, "%d", &numArray[i]) == 1 && i < 100) 
    {
        if(i < 50)
            fprintf(fPtr, "%d\n", numArray[i]); //write to file 1
        else
            fprintf(fPtr2, "%d\n", numArray[i]); //write to file 2
        i++;
    }
    fclose(stream);
    fclose(fPtr);
    fclose(fPtr2);
}
```

Comment: How would I be able to write the first 50 integers into values1.txt?

Comment: @newuserr, you can use `while (fscanf(stream, "%d", &numArray[i]) == 1 && i < 50)`. This will only read and write the first 50 values.If you want to read all and write only 50 just place a condition in `fprintf(fPtr, "%d\n", numArray[i++]);` like `int j = 0;` and `while (j++ < 50) fprintf(fPtr, "%d\n", numArray[i++]);`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: For the other half, can I write :                                                 ``` while (fscanf(stream, "%d", &numArray[j]) == 1 && j<100) input, 
    {
        fprintf(fPtr2, "%d\n", numArray[j++]);   //write to file


    }``` where int j=50 and FILE *fPtr2 = NULL;
    fPtr = fopen("values2.txt", "w"); ?

Comment: @newuserr I changed the code, it now writes the first 50 values to values1.txt and the second 50 values to values2.txt.

Comment: @newuserr, I use `i` only, but you can do it like you asked in the comment if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach that uses `getline()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SPLIT_POINT 50

int main(void) {
    char filename[] = "test";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open %s\n", filename);
    }

    // Check file open (as above) left out for brevity
    FILE *out1 = fopen("values1.txt", "w");
    FILE *out2 = fopen("values2.txt", "w");
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t n = 0, i = 0;
    ssize_t len = 0;
    while ((len = getline(&line, &n, fp)) != EOF) {
        // Select which output file to write to
        FILE *out = i < SPLIT_POINT ? out1 : out2;

        // getline includes the newline - remove this
        if (i == SPLIT_POINT - 1 && len > 0) {
            line[--len] = 0;
        }
        // Write to the relevant output file
        fprintf(out, "%s", line);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(out1);
    fclose(out2);
    free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't care about removing newlines, you could simplify the `getline()` call - just don't bother with the `len` variable.